# Assign method to delegate through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I got stuck up while dynamically assigning methods to a delegate instance through reflection. Below is a sample scenario of the situation i am faced with.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new DynamicDelegateTest().Test();            
    }
}

public class DynamicDelegateTest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        //This is what i target to do through reflection
        ABC objABC1 = new ABC();
        objABC1.Proc = Debugger;
        objABC1.Test("Helloz");

        //Implementing the same code through reflection
        ABC objABC = new ABC();
        MethodInfo MIDebugger = GetType().GetMethod("Debugger", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        FieldInfo MyProc = objABC.GetType().GetField("Proc", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        //This is the point where I got stuck up
        MyProc.SetValue(objABC, MIDebugger);
        objABC.Test("QWERTY");  
    }

    void Debugger(object Tests)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Tests);
    }
}

public class ABC
{
    public delegate void Delg(object P1);
    public Delg Proc;

    public void Test(object Tst)
    {
        if (Proc != null) Proc(Tst);
    }
}
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to get the delegate instance, rather than a method-info. For non-static methods this also includes the target instance. In this case:

```
object del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(MyProc.FieldType, this, MIDebugger);
MyProc.SetValue(objABC, del);
```